# Bluetooth speaker paired successfully but services not showing - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I have connected external Bluetooth dongle and installed drivers correctly.

I have also paired my Bluetooth speaker but it's not playing. Services are not showing in settings. Please help to fix this issue. My laptop is Acer E1-571.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I see that it's probably drivers problem , you have a missing Bluetooth service which can be found in Bluetooth drivers , try checking drivers in device manager and try reinstalling again using some programs like driverpack solution..